# Is there a way to save the favorite answer?

Tags: support, bookmarks

I know that one can vote up other people's question and the answer or comment to that question. I am wondering that if there is a way to "save" or "mark" the favorite questions or answers from others? It seems that one can only do this for his/her own questions.

Edit: I think my question should be: **how to go back to the questions or answers I like?**

Comment: Note the star below the up/downvote arrows in questions...

Comment: [...and as soon as you've set your favorites...](http://math.stackexchange.com/users/9464/jack?tab=favorites)

Comment: I will point out that now there are two things which are available for answers, too. One can add answers to [saves](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/tags/saves/info), And one can [follow](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/tags/follow-post/info) answers.
Saves are mentioned, for example, here: [Can we have a favorite star for answers?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/22149) Following was mentioned, for example, here: [Is there any way to add a bookmark to any answer of a question?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/32838)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the favorite star under the voting arrows on questions to mark a question as a favorite.

Then you can find these favorite questions in your user profile, under the favorites tab.

Comment: So, per "questions or answers" is there any inclination to have a "favorite answer" button? The only place where I would see a difference is when a question has a great many answers.

Comment: @carl all favorites are at the question level at this time, but you can bookmark questions in your browser using the "link" menu item next to each answer -- in Firefox at least you can right click and select "Bookmark This Link" directly, but I don't see that option in Chrome or IE9.

Answer (score 0):

In the Firefox Browser, I use the "favorites" button to save things I want to go back to. I believe that similar features are available in other browsers and so this isn't something that stack exchange needs to address.

Comment: But, that doesn't give much info about the problem, compared to looking at your favorite questions on stack exchange.  So, it could be something that stack exchange looked into.